# Azure CLI returns error on Storage access

Tags: azure-storage, azure-cli

I'm on a Linux machine trying to use the Azure CLI `az` to list storages

```
az storage blob list --container-name <name> --account-name <name> --account-key <key>
```

when executing it returns the error

```
azure.common.AzureHttpError: One of the request inputs is out of range. ErrorCode: OutOfRangeInput
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>OutOfRangeInput</Code><Message>One of the request inputs is out of range.
RequestId:bf2b4b1d-401e-0055-1678-d80520000000
Time:2019-03-12T02:08:42.4135303Z</Message></Error>
```

I can't find any documentation that explains the error?

Comment: @jww It is a question of Azure CLI, not network, which is also a programming question like powershell, there are a lot of questions like this in stack overflow, could you look into the question carefully before you downvoting and voting to close it??

Comment: Generally speaking, Azure CLI is off-topic at Stack Overflow. This particular question is not an exception. The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/) details what is on-topic and off-topic.

Comment: @jww I have never heard about this. I think it meets the requirements of  `a specific programming problem` and `software tools commonly used by programmers` in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: That portion of the Help Center has not materially changed since about 2012. You missed the other part: *"and is ... a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"*. Otherwise, the kitchen and coffee maker would be on-topic at Stack Overflow. (Or in this case, managing a server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, make sure your `--account-name` is in lowercase, e.g. it should be `--account-name 'teststorage'`, not `--account-name 'Teststorage'`.

[image]

[image]